# Recover ifstream after failbit is set due to a "wrong" read

Tags: c++, ifstream

I'm reading a file line by line:

```
if (std::wifstream logFile(file))
{
    std::wstring line;
    while (std::getline(logFile, line))
    {
        do_fancy_things(line);
    }
}
```

But the file `file` is never fully readed. After some debugging I've found that the file stream stops reading after reading the following line:

> ```
> (000008) 23/11/2021 16:28:53 - (not logged in) (172.25.1.1)> ü²dû–íÉS~}!ßŸT>‹6H‡c“²ìF%>4#)è Ý&ÕH6þ‡fO”ss¨–Á„“Zë´ÂS¿.¬¼dÅ
> ```

After reading the line above, the stream have `failbit` and `eofbit` set but 95% of the file still remains to be read, my bet is that all the *garbage-like* contents of the line might have caused some kind of error and I've assumed that I can reset the `failbit` in order to keep reading:

```
if (std::wifstream logFile(file))
{
    bool keepReading = true;

    do
    {
        keepReading = std::getline(logFile, line);

        if (logFile.fail())
            logFile.clear();
        else
            do_fancy_things(line);
    }
    while (keepReading);
}
```

But it didn't work. Is there a way to ignore this kind of error and reset the file stream to a state that it can keep reading the file? Or should I reopen the file and skip to a point after the failure?

Comment: Are you on a Windows system? Then when you open a file in text-mode (the default) the byte generated by `Ctrl-Z` (`26`) will actually act as an end-of-file, even when reading files (IIRC). Have you checked the contents of the file and that line with a hex-editor to see the actual bytes?

Comment: As for how to solve your problem, you need to clear the `eofbit` as well, which isn't done by `clear`. You should be able to do it by seeking to the current position.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude you're right, that line contains two `0x19` bytes.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude: If I understand the documentation of [`clear`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/clear) correctly, it does clear `eofbit`, assuming that the default function argument `goodbit` is used.

Comment: *"that line contains two 0x19 bytes"* What happens when you [ignore](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/ignore) those bytes? Have you tried opening the file as binary?

Comment: @Bob__ I didn't tried to ignore those bytes, what I've tried (and it worked) is to clear the error flags and then `seekg` to the last position (`tellg`) if the last position is not the size of the file.

Comment: Okay I was wrong about the `eofbit` but the underlying OS file handle is probably still in its end-of-file state. Seeking should hopefully clear that at least.

Comment: @PaperBirdMaster: According to what I read and also according to my own tests on Microsoft Windows, I don't think that it is bytes with the value `0x19` that cause trouble, but rather bytes with the value `0x1A`.